# I want to develop an android VOIP app using PJSIP stack by its high level api i.e. PJSUA2

Tags: android, sip, pjsip, pjsua2

I want to develop an Android VOIP app, for which I've chosen PJSIP library. So far I have searched this, but all the help and stuff are quite old like 3 to 4 years old. Its high level API is PJSUA2 (C++) but most of the help and community problems are about PJSIP basic api (Coded in C). 
So I want to know if somebody has any knowledge about PJSUA2 usage in Java or has developed an app using PJSUA2 in recent years. 
Note: I have to develop this in Android Studio

Comment: did u implemented the same? I had done it, and can help u if needed.

Comment: Yeah sure. I had left working over the project but today saw your comment so thought I should see it again. I'd be delighted if u share some knowledge. Looking forward to you.

Answer (score 1):

I am also having the same scenario. I had tried building Pjsip library, but some of the files never get compiled. If you want to develop a simple voip application you can refer general android sip api. refer [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip)

When it comes to tedious tasks like video recording and conference call, we want external libraries. But no recent updates regarding pjsip for me.

Comment: did you achieved your goal (working simple voip app)? I'm fighting with this built-in API, but it is a nightmare... I'm seeing on stack that you have posted a lot of questions, most of them without answers... :(

Comment: @snachmsm 
Yes brother. I had successfully build the library and my app is running on it efficiently :)